# Python Tornado tcpserver stream write result

Tags: python, sockets, stream, tornado, tcpserver

I have a simple tornado tcp server that sometimes writes to client streams.

I want to get the result of stream.write(). It always returns None regardless of whether the stream is still active or not.

I have tried using stream.write() with a callback and coroutine.

Is there a way of actually getting the result of stream.write() ?

Here is the code.

```
import logging
import signal
import tornado.httpserver
import datetime
from tornado import gen


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Server(tornado.httpserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, io_loop=None, ssl_options=None, **kwargs):

        logger.debug('tcp server started')

        if not io_loop:
            io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

        self.io_loop = io_loop
        self.streams = []

        self.io_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), self.write_to_all_stream)

        tornado.httpserver.TCPServer.__init__(
            self, io_loop=io_loop, ssl_options=ssl_options, **kwargs
        )        


    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        logger.debug('New connection from %s' % str(address))
        self.streams.append(stream)


    def on_write_stream(self):
        logger.debug('written to stream')


    #@gen.coroutine
    def write_to_all_stream(self):
        logger.debug('writing to all streams')

        for s in self.streams:
            if s.closed():
                logger.debug('Stream is closed!')
            else:
                result = s.write('hello', self.on_write_stream)
                #result = yield s.write('hello')

                logger.debug('result: %s' % str(result))


def configure_signals():
    def bye_handler(signal, frame):
        logger.info('interrupt signal received, shutting down')

        io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        io_loop.stop()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, bye_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, bye_handler)


def configure_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=None,
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)7s: [%(name)s]: %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_signals()
    configure_logging()

    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    logger.debug('hello')

    s = Server().listen(12345, '127.0.0.1')

    loop.start()

    logger.debug('bye')
```

For testing client streams I use nc ( netcat ). I simulate a disconnect with `CTRL + C` / `CTRL + Z`

```
nc 127.0.0.1 12345
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Python: 2.7.6

Tornado version: 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a bit and testing various things I have found the answer.

```
BaseIOStream.get_fd_error()
```

Which states:

> Returns information about any error on the underlying file.
>
> This method is called after the IOLoop has signaled an error on the file descriptor, and should return an Exception (such as socket.error with additional information, or None if no such information is available.

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/iostream.html#tornado.iostream.BaseIOStream.get_fd_error

Here is the updated version for the above code. It detects stream errors if they occur.

```
import logging
import signal
import tornado.httpserver
import datetime
import functools


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Server(tornado.httpserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, io_loop=None, ssl_options=None, **kwargs):
        
        logger.debug('tcp server started')

        if not io_loop:
            io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

        self.io_loop = io_loop
        self.streams = []
        
        self.io_loop.add_timeout(datetime.timedelta(seconds=5), self.write_to_all_stream)
        
        tornado.httpserver.TCPServer.__init__(
            self, io_loop=io_loop, ssl_options=ssl_options, **kwargs
        )        


    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        logger.debug('New connection from %s' % str(address))
        self.streams.append(stream)


    def on_write_stream(self, stream):
        status = stream.get_fd_error()
        
        if status[0]:
            logger.debug('Encountered an error when writing to stream: %s' % str(status[1]))
        else:
            logger.debug('Successfully written to stream')


    def write_to_all_stream(self):
        logger.debug('writing to all streams')
        
        for s in self.streams:
            s.write('hello', functools.partial(self.on_write_stream, s))

 
def configure_signals():
    def bye_handler(signal, frame):
        logger.info('interrupt signal received, shutting down')

        io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
        io_loop.stop()

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, bye_handler)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, bye_handler)


def configure_logging():
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=None,
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s: %(levelname)7s: [%(name)s]: %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    configure_signals()
    configure_logging()
    
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    
    logger.debug('hello')
    
    s = Server().listen(12345, '127.0.0.1')
    
    loop.start()
    
    logger.debug('bye')
```

**UPDATE:**

stream.write() is not 100% reliable for TCP connections. stream.get_fd_error() returns (0, 'Success') when the data is put on the OS queue without error but does not guarantee that it reaches the client. For that you need to implement a confirmation system on the app level.

more details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3579609/5069752