# Why network service build on tcp need ping pong logic?

Tags: tcp, websocket

I currently use `websocket`, and in [rfc6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-37):

> Upon receipt of a Ping frame, an endpoint MUST send a Pong frame in
> response, unless it already received a Close frame.  It SHOULD respond
> with Pong frame as soon as is practical.

`Websocket` prefer a `Pong` respond to `Ping`. But if a `Ping` can send success over a tcp connection, should this mean the connection is still alive, why need remote to respond with a `Pong`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related

Comment: It might be because of this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578650/c-socket-does-send-wait-for-recv-to-end). Application layer need `Ping` `Pong` maybe because when call `send`, we can only know data is copied to the network stack successfully, and `tcp` layer doesn't report to us when the data is really transferred.

Maybe someone can explain the design more detail...

Answer (score 0):

Because in case of proxies, PING/PONG gives you the end to end check, while TCP mechanisms only assure you can send till next hop.

PING/PONG is also intended to measure performance, you can PING sending a timestamp, and the PONG will echo it.